# Cannot create EAttachmentRule variable in a Blueprint struct

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I'm trying to add a EAttachmentRule variable in a struct but the enum doesn't appear in the list of available types

[image]

I managed to create a variable in a BP by dragging the pin from an AttachActorToComponent node and promoting it to a variable. But I can't do the same thing to create a variable in a struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like that is not possible.  The easiest way around it would be to create an Enum with the same options (KeepRelative, KeepWorld, SnapToTarget) as the EAttachmentRule Enum and use that instead.